# passing global variables to another file in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have

```
# file1.py
global a, b, c, d, e, f, g

def useful1():
   # a lot of things that uses a, b, c, d, e, f, g

def useful2():
   useful1()
   # a lot of things that uses a, b, c, d, e, f, g

def bonjour():
   # a lot of things that uses a, b, c, d, e, f, g
   useful2()
```

and

```
# main.py   (main file)
import file1

# here I would like to set the value of a, b, c, d, e, f, g  of file1 !

bonjour()
```

**How to deal with all these global variables ?**

*PS : I don't want to add `a, b, c, d, e, f, g` for ALL functions, it would be very redundant to have to do :*

```
def useful1(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
...
def useful2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
...
def bonjour(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
...
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, since those global variables only exist inside the file.

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  What exactly do you expect your global statement to be doing?  `global` at the top-level of a file is an effectively useless statement.  `global` only has meaning for identifiers *inside* a function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to pass them. If you've done `import file1` at the top of main.py, you can just refer to `file1.a` etc directly.

However, having this many global variables smells very bad. You probably should refactor using a class.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to share information across modules within a single program is to create a special module (often called config or cfg). Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the module then becomes available as a global name. Because there is only one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get reflected everywhere. **For example:**

**config.py:**

```
x = 0   # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting
```

**mod.py:**

```
import config
config.x = 1
```

**main.py:**

```
import config
import mod
print config.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict to wrap those global variable, then only one param for functions

Comment: thank you. can you give just a simple example in this context with dict?